# Unity3d 4.6 beta17 UI Restrict input text to numbers only

Tags: validation, unity-game-engine

As the title says, is there a way to restrict the input text to numbers only? I am using unity3d 4.6.0 beta17

**EDIT:** So it seems that the solution would be to:

```
public InputField input;

void Start () {
    input.keyboardType = TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad;
    input.validation = InputField.Validation.Integer;
}
```

or easier, with `debug inspector` on and select: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switch the inspector to debug mode then you can access a field called KeyboardType and change it to whatever you want